# GitHub pull request builder unable to connect to GitHub

Tags: jenkins, github, jenkins-plugins, github-api

Good afternoon.
I'm using plugin version 1.42.0.
Recently I receive a token deprecation notice in my mailbox. 
I regenerated the token and now I'm not able to connect to Github at all through this plugin.

I tried different types of credentials - email + password, secret text, email + password (where the token is the password), no luck.

[image]

Please note that credentials are valid, I'm able to connect to GitHub through other plugins.

Am I missing something very obvious here?

PS. No 2-factor auth is enabled for my account.
I'm not an admin account, but I'm able to read and write everything into the repo.

Answer (score 0):

Well, my bad.
I was so tired, that I did not put a repository name into the field above.

Everything is working now.